# Is there a reference to Puranas in the Atharvaveda?

Tags: vedas, puranas

Atharvana Veda 11.7.24 says:

> ऋचः सामानि च्छन्दांसि पुराणम् यजुषा सह ।
>
> उच्छिष्टाज्जज्ञिरे सर्वे दिवि देवा दिविश्रितः ॥ २४॥

Is this a reference to Puranas (the traditional well-known Puranas like Agni, Matsya, Kurma, Skanda, Shiva, Padma, Varaha etc)?

Comment: Your question is confusing. You said Puranas of the Itihasa, there is no such a thing called "Puranas of the Itihasa".

Comment: [This](http://www.aryasamajjamnagar.org/atharvaveda_v2/pages/p434.gif) is the translation from Arya Samaj Btw.

Comment: @brahmajijnasa I meant the traditional puranas. There is a sanskrit meaning of puranas (`pura api navam` meaning `new (relevant) even if it's old`) and I wanted to differentiate from that.

Comment: @Pandya the hindi translation seems to mean the traditional Puranas right?